# No server certificate trust in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, azure, security, certificate, azure-sql-database

If you create a regular Azure SQL database and go to "Connection strings" tab in the portal all the connection strings have `TrustServerCertificate=False` parameter. Why is that? Microsoft doesn't trust its own certificates?

**Update**:
I guess it's just poor naming. Found this in [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.trustservercertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

> When `TrustServerCertificate` is set to `true`, the transport layer will
> use SSL to encrypt the channel and bypass walking the certificate
> chain to validate trust. If `TrustServerCertificate` is set to `true` and
> encryption is turned on, the encryption level specified on the server
> will be used even if `Encrypt` is set to `false`. The connection will fail
> otherwise.

Comment: It's a bit like clicking the "ignore certificate error" in your browser: you haven't actually proved who you are talking to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TrustServerCertificate=true` means the client will trust the certificate it gets from SQL server without fully verifying it. And this is obviously a bad thing so **always use `TrustServerCertificate=false`**.

Comment: I don't get it. If a client doesn't trust a cert it cannot establish a secure connection, can it?

Comment: It's up to the client to decide what it does with a certificate it gets from a server. One part of the certificate verification process is checking if the certificate was signed by an authority the client inherently trusts (these are the root certificates that are installed on the machine). TrustServerCertificate=true skips this check which means, the client just accepts the certificate even if it was never signed by a CA which root certificates are installed on the client's machine.